# Como ficaria o insert numa tabela que só tem chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho um cadastro de usuários e esse cadastro pode ser feito de duas maneiras, pelo facebook ou pelo e-mail. A minha dúvida seria como dar o insert nessas tabela, pois tenho uma tabela de controle que recebe os ids das outras duas tabelas por chave estrangeira.

Tabela:[image: Tabela do meu trabalho]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o usuário se cadastrar a partir de um e-mail, ficaria algo como:

```
INSERT INTO user (id_user, nome, email, senha) VALUES (DEFAULT, "Fulano", "foo@lano.com", "1234");
INSERT INTO user_controller (id_controller, id_user) VALUES (DEFAULT, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

A primeira linha adiciona os dados do usuário em `user` e a segunda insere a chave estrangeira na tabela de relação `user_controller`. Neste caso, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` retornará o valor de `id_user` gerado na primeira instrução.

Para o cadastro a partir do Facebook seria algo bem semelhante:

```
INSERT INTO user_fb (id_userfb, nome, sobrenome, idfacebook) VALUES (DEFAULT, "Fulano", "Snow", "314159");
INSERT INTO user_controller (id_controller, id_userfb) VALUES (DEFAULT, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Neste caso, a chave estrangeira seria escrita na coluna `id_userfb`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu tenho mais uma duvida poderia me ajudar pf?

Comment: Basta criar uma nova pergunta no site com ela.