# Inserir Chave primaria e estrangeira ao "mesmo tempo" SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suponha duas tabelas "empresa" e "funcionario" dentro de funcionario tem uma foreign key para a empresa

Quando o usuario vai criar uma nova empresa ele responde um form que nesse form ele adiciona o nome dos funcionarios

o que eu quero fazer : Quando ele clicar 'submit', criar a empresa e pegar o ID dela. Depois com o ID criar os funcionarios e colocar esse ID na chave estrangeira

Como pego esse ID ? Preciso fazer um query pro banco ou tem jeito mais facil ? Pq ela é gerado automatico pelo banco, com a funcao de auto incremento dele. Eu nao passo manualmente

Comment: Outra: [Fazer insert em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107739/5878)

Comment: Outra: [Como ficaria o insert numa tabela que só tem chave estrangeira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209588/5878)